# Getting a size from a loaded file via a File variable type ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

Cannot get my file size! I have a variable that loads the file, and then on my fileCompleteLoad event i want to check the size of that file (.png).

`// clickButton event to load the file`

```
public function onMouseClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    _fileRef = new File();
    _fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected, false, 0, true);
    _fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onCancel, false, 0, true);
    _fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError, false, 0, true);
    _fileRef.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, 
    onSecurityError,  false, 0, true);

    _fileRef.browse([_imageFilter]);
}

// selected event

public function onFileSelected(evt:Event):void
{
    _fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress, false, 0, true);
    _fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);
    _fileRef.load();
}


// thats my eventComplete

 public function onComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    _msgSuccessErrorTextField.text = "File was successfully loaded.";
    _pngInputTextField.text = String(_fileRef.nativePath);
    _atfOutputTextField.text = _fileRef.nativePath.replace(".png",".atf");
    _inputNativeProcess = _fileRef.nativePath;
    _outputNativeProcess = _atfOutputTextField.text;
    _flagLoadedFile = new Boolean(true);

    var test:Bitmap = evt.target.data as Bitmap;
    if(test){
        trace(test.height);
    }

    _fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected);
    _fileRef.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    _fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    _fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onCancel);
```

Now, in that event i want to check my file size... I ve tried many things but didnt get success... and sometimes i get null from my _fileRef.data.

Any suggestions to solve that?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Answer is -

`//add that on my public function onComplete(evt:Event):void{}`

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.loadBytes(byteArray);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);

// build another event

publicfunction loaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(loaderInfo.width,
loaderInfo.height, false,   0xFFFFFF);

bitmapData.draw(loaderInfo.loader);
// result: bitmapData
```

}

now i can get the Heigh, witdh and whatever... thx!

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure, are you getting the `data` inside the `onComplete` handler? The code you show doesn't do that right now. Should be something like :

```
_fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);

private function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var test:Bitmap = e.target.data as Bitmap;
    if(test)
        trace(test.height);
}
```

Comment: i did what u said, but still not working... it says that my test:Bitmap is receiving NULL, not actually the file. I edit my question with my event. take a look

Comment: What are the types of `e.target` and `e.target.data`? Is `e.target.data` NULL too?

Comment: `_browsePngTextFiledButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseClick, false, 0, true);`

Comment: my e.target.data is not null... its has the nativepath, url and others

Comment: Is anything in there the actual loaded image data? You should use that for the bitmap.

Comment: The documentation for `File` says `data` is a byte array. You might need to convert that to a bitmap. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#data
See this to do that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541730/bytearray-to-bitmapdata-as3/11542166#11542166

Comment: i tried everything...always come null... `var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.loadBytes(evt.target.data);

        var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(evt.target.data as BitmapData);`

Comment: i got this: `<Error: Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information.>`

Comment: maybe my copleteEvent is not completed?

Comment: You can put a break point inside the onComplete handler and see if it is being called at all.

Comment: i debugged.. actually it load the file but i cant attribute the loaded file to another variable..