# AS3 - Is there an equivalent decode() to BitmapData.encode()?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

Is there a way to turn the ByteArray back into a BitmapData after using BitmapData.encode()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ByteArray to BitmapData AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541730/bytearray-to-bitmapdata-as3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. You have to use `Loader` to load encoded JPEG and access bitmap data through the loaded content:

```
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(100, 100, false, 0xFF0000));
    addChild(bitmap);

    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bitmap.bitmapData.encode(bitmap.bitmapData.rect, new JPEGEncoderOptions(), bytes);
    bitmap.bitmapData.dispose();

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void
    {
        var bd:BitmapData = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;

        bitmap.bitmapData = bd;
    });
    loader.loadBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: Well actually, it IS a way to "turn back" the ByteArray. +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Introduced with `AIR 50.0` there now is `BitmapData.decode()`:

> Decompresses encoded image data (PNG/GIF89a/JPEG) into a new BitmapData object using data provided in a ByteArray. The image format is determined by the runtime and supports the same formats as can be provided within a SWF file's DefineBitsJPEG2 tag.

https://airsdk.dev/reference/actionscript/3.0/flash/display/BitmapData.html#decode()