# View documents (common file types) in browser (IE 7+) for Flex 4 web applications

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have implemented upload/download functionality for my Flex 4 application. I want to view the uploaded document in the browser (primarily in IE 7+). I have the FileReference object which saves/downloads the attachment on the machine. I have stored the document in the Oracle Database as a `BLOB` and on Flex side as `ByteArray` object.

Is there any way I can view the document in browser without downloading the file?

Comment: No. If you don't download the file, it's on the server, hence you can't view it. Not with Flex, not with any other client-side technology. For lack of better words: you're trying to bend the laws of physics.

Comment: Client-side I have ByteArray object. Can't I use that to display the file in browser?

Comment: Inside the Flex app, yes (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541730/bytearray-to-bitmapdata-as3); but not natively in the browser.